# Xamarin Android activity restarts itself

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

This question is already asked [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/32931/android-application-restarting), but no one has answered this yet.

**The Problem :**

I have created a `Xamarin.Forms` application. I am using `Moto X Developer Edition` running `Android 5.1` to test this application. When the application starts everything runs okay, but if I keep it open and do nothing on it, the activity will `restart` after few minutes, this resets the current state of my application and goes to my initial login page.

**Test to confirm if it was the activity or application :**

I have two activities. One is the `SplashScreen` activity which is the `MainLauncher` and the other one is from where my `FormsApplication` starts. I kept breakpoint on `OnCreate` method in both the activities. Launched my application in debuge mode and tested the scenario above. After a few minutes the Activity from which my `FormsApplication` starts hits the breakpoint and not the MainLauncher activity. So it is to do with the activiy where my forms application loads and not the whole application.

I thought it would happen with Android clearing the applications to free the RAM. But my application is not paused. It is focused on the screen.

I don't know why this is happening. Has anyone faced this problem?

**Activity**

```
[Activity(Label = "SplashScreenActivity", Theme = "@style/Theme.Main", ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
    public class SplashScreenActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you let the screen turn off?

Comment: Nope it was on..@jzeferino

Comment: What version of `Xamarin.Android`? What version of `Xamarin.Forms`?

Comment: Any way to share the code or a video of the problem?

Comment: It seems to be the problem of my device. I created another application, the same problem occurred there also.@jzeferino

Comment: My comment above. But its a strange behaviour. I don't know maybe my application might be eating up the ram. I checked the ram though almost 1GB of the ram remain free. CPU usage is also normal. @SushiHangover

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not sure it have something to do with it, but try to add this in your [Activity] flag :

```
LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTask
```

It primarily allows to keep an instance of the activity alive at all times, even if it's backgrounded. Again, not sure it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Just taking a stab at it but there's a lot of weirdness with the Android activity lifecycle. The OS seems to have considerable flexibility in terms of when it destroys, recycles, etc. an activity. In any case, regardless of whether this solves the original problem or not it's a good idea to make sure that you handle these cases (e.g. making sure that it's doing necessary state restores in OnCreate/OnResume/etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the attribute property to the Main Activity

```
 [Activity(
     Label = "MainActivity",ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.ScreenSize
 )]
```

It might be helpful.